# Symfony 1.4 flash message not showing in prod env, but does in dev

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I did find another question with a similar title to my question but there was no solution.

Basically, a flash message I'm setting (and persist is true) is not showing after I re-direct a user to a different page, but the problem only exists with my production environment.

If I use the frontend_dev.php controller, the flash message shows correctly.

I've tried completely clearing my cache (cd cache; rm -rf *) but this doesn't make any difference.

The question with a similar issue is here for reference:
[Can't use flash method in prod environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453237/cant-use-flash-method-in-prod-environment)

Any ideas?

I've inspected the elements on the page to make sure the flash message definitely isn't there (and isn't being hidden by javascript or anything like that).

Cheers